Cache tags not bubbling up correctly in blocks
I have a custom block that contains a media field (field_featured_media). I noticed if the alt text of that image is updated, it does not reflect in my block unless the site cache is cleared. After debugging, I notice that the cache tag for media:[id] does not exist on the page. I figured that the block should already know about the media cache tag?
I also have this line at the bottom of my twig template:
{{ {'#cache': content['#cache']}|render }}
I figured the media cache tag would bubble up correctly, but I guess this is not the case?
One thing I want to note...I am not rendering field_featured_media directly in my twig template like I am for our content types. In my content type twig templates I am just doing this: {{ content.field_featured_media }} and the cache tags get passed to the page correctly.
The way I am rendering them in my blocks is different. I'm actually using a custom twig filter to get the image src and alt text, and then passing them to a custom element via .setAttribute inside twig.
Should I be expecting the media cache tag to exist in my case? Or do I need to pass that cache tag through myself?

Beyond @4uk4's explanation, the TL,DR: answer for this question is: use {% set dummy_enforce_all_caches = content|render %}. This will bulk collect all cache tags and contexts.

As a rule of thumb: avoid drilling in templates. You easily bypass permissions and caching by accident. Use view modes and (custom) field formatters instead.

Everything you describe in the question makes sense. In content['#cache']  you'll find the cache metadata of the block, not of the content referenced in different fields. This metadata bubbles up when rendered but not when you extract only some attributes.
BTW Twig filters can bubble up metadata, too. If you don't want to change how the template is rendering the field, you can add a PHP statement to the filter to render a #cache array containing the cache tag of the media entity.
